# How can I get and print multiple columns of a table into HTML5? (django, sqlite, html5)

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-models, sqlite

### The Core informations:

- using Django, HTML5 and sqlite
- wish to create a webpage where on each page only the first column of the data and another  column is shown

## Problem

- the program doesn't recognise a local variable and cannot iterate/list the needed data in to html

### Explanation of the variables

- `concept_name` and `reka_1` -> the name of the columns in the model

Thank you for your answers in advance!

The error message that I am getting:

TemplateSyntaxError at /concepts/chapter1/
Could not parse the remainder: '% for concept in concept_chapter_1 %' from '% for concept in concept_chapter_1 %'

Views.py

```
def chapter_1(request):
concept_chapter_1 = Concept.objects.values('concept_name', 'reka_1')
return render(request, 'concepts/chapter_1.html',{'concept_chapter_1':concept_chapter_1})
```

Urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^chapter1/$', views.chapter_1, name = 'chapter1'),
    url(r'^chapter2/$', views.chapter_2, name = 'chapter2'),

hmtl5

```
  {{% for concept in concept_chapter_1 %}}

  <tr>
    <td>{{ concept.concept_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ concept.reka_1 }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post the code instead of images? It would be easier for people to help you that way

Comment: thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

It surprises me the most but found a possible solution to the program. There were multiple problems in my previous code. I would not dare to explain why and how this works, it just works after a lot of trying and modifying, I hope it can help others

The new and working version to print two columns from the data to html

views.py

```
def chapter_1(request):
concept_chapter_1 = Concept.objects.values('concept_name', 'reka_1')
concept = {"concepts_chapter1": concept_chapter_1}
return render(request, 'concepts/chapter_1.html', context=concept)
```

html

```
{% if concepts_chapter1 %}
<table>
  <thead>
  <th>Concept</th>
  <th>Records</th>
  </thead>

  {% for randomobject in concepts_chapter1 %}

  <tr>
    <td>{{ randomobject.concept_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ randomobject.reka_1 }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```